# Using Eclipse Scala IDE v3.7.2 what is the key assist for multi-line commenting out of code?

Tags: eclipse, scala

Over the years, have worked with various versions of Eclipse for various programming languages (C, C++, Java, Python, Groovy etc) and now Scala. Eclipse is a great IDE.

I always also install Vrapper plugin as I like VIM bindings in Editor. On MAC, multi-line comments are usually supported by highlighting the lines to comment / uncomment and hitting Command Shift C.

This does not work on Scala Eclipse IDE v3.7.2 (http://scala-ide.org/) and the key assist (command shift L) does not appear to have a keyboard shortcut for comments listed.

Am I missing something obvious here?

I tried various other combinations (control /, control 7 etc) and nothing is working.

Anyone with experience using Scala Eclipse IDE - really appreciate a tip on how to get this working. It's one of those productivity assists I have always taken for granted. Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: OK, just found an explanation. It appears the usual comment keyboard shortcut (command shift C) DOES work for "Scala class" files. For some reason it does not work when using an "Scala Worksheet" files. Using Scala perspective in both cases. This must be a shortcoming of the worksheet editor.

Comment: Indeed, the worksheet editor does not have this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments above, and confirmation by lulian Dragos - keyboard shortcut (command shift C) DOES work for "Scala class" files. However, it is not currently supported when using a "Scala Worksheet" file type.